# How do I avoid date type column of MSSQL INTO PIVOTAL HAWQ null at DBMS migration

Tags: sql-server, data-conversion, hawq

We are trying to pull data from external source (mssql) to postgres. But when i checked  for  invoicedate column entries are getting blank at the same time mssql  is showing invoicedate values for those entries.

ie
We tried following query on both the DBMS:

When query executed in SQL Server:

```
select * from tablename where salesorder='168490'
```

getting 12 rows where invoicedate column is `'2015-10-26 00:00:00.000'`

But same query is executed on Postgres

```
select "InvoceDt" from tablename where salesorder='168490'
```

Getting 12 rows where the column invoicedate is null.

Question is why? 
Postgres `InvoiceDt` column is coming null rather than we can see that SQL Server is  showing appropriate data values.

Why is the data different between SQL Server and Postgres for this particular column?

Comment: how do you copy the data?  And hat is the data type of that column in Postgres and SQL Server?

Comment: There is also a mismatch in the column names: `invoicedate` vs. `InvoceDt` is that a copy & paste error in your question or do they really differ? If they _do_ differ then maybe your tool that copies the data cannot match the two columns.

Comment: data type of  that column(invoicedate) is date in postgres and datetime in mssql. we are using spring-xd tool for data ingestion. and data type of salesorder is char in mssql and salesorder is  character(6)  in postgres

Comment: it is my typing mistake here both column same here column name is InvoiceDt  for both  mssql server and postgres db

Comment: same time we are getting  values  for InvoiceDt  in postgres as well when  i search for DISTINCT VALUES OF InvoiceDt.

Comment: Why do you store date **and** time in SQL Server, but only the date in Postgres? Maybe that's why your migration tool doesn't copy the values. Without the actual migration code, this is impossible to answer

Comment: when we created DDL in postgres  for table which consist of InvoiceDt so we tried  to keep datetime type  of mssql as  corresponding  data type for postgres but it is  not supported at the same time when we created postgres DDL with  date . it is working

Comment: The corresponding data type is `timestamp`

Comment: Yes, Exactly i tried with  but it is  not picking timestamp so i replaced with  date

Comment: I have no idea what "*it is not picking timestamp*" is supposed to mean. Postgres most certainly supports a data type named `timestamp`.

Comment: CREATE  TABLE tablename
 (
 "InvoiceDt" timestamp 
 )
 LOCATION ('pxf://hostname/path/to/hdfs/?profile=HdfsTextSimple')
 FORMAT 'csv' ( delimiter '^' null 'null' quote '~');

Comment: Here is my  new  ddl statement in which  mapping is timestamp as discussed here but getting same null values in InvoiceDt column for particular salesorder entry

Comment: That is not a valid Postgres statement. Are you _sure_ you are using Postgres? (And please do not post code in comments, **edit** your question)

Comment: we are using postgres code 8.2 my postgres version is PostgreSQL 8.2.15 originally it is HAWQ VERSION IS 1.3.0

Comment: As I said: that is **not** valid for Postgres. Neither for the current nor for the outdated and unsupported version 8.2 - plus it seems that data is coming from a CSV file, not from SQL Server

Comment: our external source is mssql . as discussed spring xd is tool which is ingesting file into hadoop  in csv format then i am reading through hawq  which is postgres 8.2

Comment: when i am  READING same query  into mssql it is giving me result for InvoiceDt as 2015-10-26 but same  thing i am reading through  pgadmin which is tool  for hawq  it is showing me null value. and even i am using unix machine for hawq it is also showing null values here

Comment: Is that possible to avoid  additional null at dbms to dbms migration  ? because  hawq is creating additional null values. or is their any way  to get actual value of InvoiceDt   as it is in mssql server at the  time of migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vicps, you aren't using Postgres and that is why a_horse_with_no_name is having such a hard time trying to understand your question.  You are using Pivotal HDB (formally called HAWQ).  HAWQ is now associated with the incubator project, "Apache HAWQ" and the commercial version is "Pivotal HDB".

Pivotal HDB is a fork of Pivotal Greenplum database which is a fork of PostgreSQL 8.2.  It has many similarities to Postgres but it is most definitely not Postgres.

You are also using Spring-XD to move the data from SQL Server to HDFS which is critical in understanding what the true problem is.

You provided this example:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename ( "InvoiceDt" timestamp ) 
LOCATION ('pxf://hostname/path/to/hdfs/?profile=HdfsTextSimple') 
FORMAT 'csv' ( delimiter '^' null 'null' quote '~');
```

Your file only has one column in it?  How is this possible?  Above, you mention the salesorder column.  Secondly, have you tried looking at the file written by Spring-XD?

```
hdfs dfs -cat hdfs://hostname:8020/path/to/hdfs | grep 168490
```

I bet you have an extra delimiter, null character, or an escape character in the data which is causing the problem.  You also may want to tag your question with spring-xd too.

Comment: BY changing ordinal position  of InvoiceDt column in my external table syntax CREATE TABLE tablename ( "InvoiceDt" timestamp ) 
LOCATION ('pxf://hostname/path/to/hdfs/?profile=HdfsTextSimple') 
FORMAT 'csv' ( delimiter '^' null 'null' quote '~'); it is working

Comment: We have such 34 column in create external table synatx but InvoiceDt is listed at 34 number  but when we changed the position  as a first column  it started taking null values into default date value. and we changed the  spring xd job  sql option as well in that  we have fixed InvoiceDt column postion as first column  in that way external table started pointing expected data .

Comment: We have not changed  our format clause. our Format clause is  FORMAT 'csv' ( delimiter '^' null 'null' quote '~') and our job delimiter='^' inside spring xd.  is  that extra delimiter is causing problem ? if it is problem then why started reading without  making any changes in it. can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The default escape character is "\" so a field with "c:\" for example, will effectively escape the trailing double quote and make you have not enough columns.  You should look at gp_read_error_log() to see the errors of these poorly formatted rows.

Comment: default  escape is picking  same special character as quote that is  '~' .and thanks for information  for gp_read_error_log() to see the  errors of these poorly formatted rows and  command you gave me earlier is also helpful  while debug.